# How to get the specific data in click of polyline?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

At the time of multiple data with the help of that I am plotting the polyline with lat and long value. Now when I'm plotting it, I'm to specific the line also because that the time of polyline click I should now the different because maybe the lat and long value will same but some when I will give specific value to that then I can know which lat and long is been click.

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.addAll(coordinateList);
polylineOptions.width(10);
polylineOptions.color(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
line.setClickable(true);
```

coordinateList is the list of lat and long value. But I want to add one specific value to get the the value when it is been clicked.

```
@Override
public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
  double latitude = polyline.getPoints().get(0).latitude;
  double longitude = polyline.getPoints().get(0).longitude;
}
```

In click I've come to know the lat and long

How I can set specific value and how I will get on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a structure (a `Map` for example) to store the data associated to the `Polyline`s. For example (storing a `String` for each `Polyline`):

```
final Map<Polyline, String> polylines = new HashMap<>();

PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.addAll(coordinateList);
polylineOptions.width(10);
polylineOptions.color(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
polylineOptions.clickable(true);

polylines.put(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions), "Polyline data");

mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, polylines.get(polyline), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: @antonia thanks for the answer but above answer will give me only one polyline data but i need all the lat,long have there specific data

Comment: @antonia in above there will be multiple polyline how ur answer specfic which polyline data is that

Comment: My solution can be used with *any* number of polylines and associates an `Object` (`String` in the example for simplicity) to each `Polyline` (I have used only one polyline to follow the example in your question).

Comment: Thank you @antonia