# how to get lat lng of position click on polyline?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

> I am getting `setOnPolylineClickListener` by following method.

```
mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
}
```

> But this returns whole `Polyline`I want `Latitude` and `Longitude`of click position like
>   we get by `MapClickListener` how to achieve this ?

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng point) {

        });
```

> I have tried using `PolyUtil` with following code it also doesn't work.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng point) {
                if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(point, finalPolylines.getPoints(), true)) {
                    // user clicked on polyline

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("found", "onMapClick:  found");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: polyline does not return lat lng, we can only set lat lng,color.

Comment: i know but is there no way to get polyline click position lat lng ?

Comment: Try this one I hope help for you...https://stackoverflow.com/a/41304033/8143436

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25198514/5110595) hope it will help you.

Comment: not woking @HemantParmar

Comment: its working IF polyline is not clickable.. how about if the polyline is clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing everything alright:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(final LatLng point) {
        if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(point, finalPolylines.getPoints(), true)) {
            // user clicked on polyline

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("found", "onMapClick:  found");
        }
    }
});
```

is the solution, but [`PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(LatLng point, java.util.List<LatLng> polyline, boolean geodesic)`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-) has 0.1 meter tolerance by default, and touch just didn't on path with this precise. Use [`PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(LatLng point, java.util.List<LatLng> polyline, boolean geodesic, double tolerance)`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-double-) instead, set appropriate `tolerance` (10 meters, or 20 meters - or even more, it depends on zoom level)

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(final LatLng point) {
        if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(point, finalPolylines.getPoints(), true, 20)) {
            // user clicked on polyline

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("found", "onMapClick:  found");
        }
    }
});
```

and everything should works!

**UPDATE:**

Also you can modify `tolerance` depending on zoom level, like:

```
...
switch (mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom) {
    ...
    case 16:
        tolerance = 30;
    break;
    case 15:
        tolerance = 45;
    break;
    ...
}
...
```

or use formula: `tolerance = f(zoom level)` like `tolerance = 1000 / mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;`.

Comment: thank you it works when zoom level is low but when zoom level is high then click outside the polyline also considered as on polyline click how do i fix that ... any suggestions?

Comment: @akshay_shahane You always can modify `tolerance` depending on zoom level, like `tolerance = 1000 / mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;` or something like that. Or use `switch/case` for each zoom level: `switch(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)  { case 16: tolerance = 30; break; case 15: tolerance = 45;` etc.

Comment: worked like charm ... thank you so much ... you saved my day

Comment: Absolutely great workaround, thanks a lot for it!