# Set marker on Polyline in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-polyline

I've tried to make possible choice on polyline in google maps. But I'm stuck.
For example: I have 10 points (with lines).

by using this part of code:

```
        polylines = new PolylineOptions();
        polylines.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.poly_line_color));

        //add path points, set colour, etc. here
        polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylines);
        polyline.setPoints(latLngs);
        polyline.setClickable(true);

        mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                Logger.e("id : "+polyline.getPoints());


            }
        });
```

we can easy detect click on polyline.  But - I can't detect current coordinates (latitude/longitude) for this click.

I tried method

> "PolyUtil"

from another library - but this is work randomly and not correct. And really - look like it does not work. 10 clicks on map = 1 good point which is not on polyline or near this line.

> Polyline polyline has only few methods and only one normal "getPoints()" but its returned all points.

Can anyone help me with this?  I checked a lot of posts on SO but none helped me.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334265/how-to-get-lat-lng-of-postion-click-on-polyline

Answer (score 0):

```
   map.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
     polyline.getPoints()
});
```

Try this function `polyline.getPoints()` in your code. This may help you. Thanks